# Laravel 5.1: SQL query 'where LIKE %word%word%word%' not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Keep in mind I have minimal SQL experience, so I may be doing it all wrong.

I'm trying to set up search for a table but simply searching for the string a user enters is not ideal because though something may come up for "steve", if a user types "steve jobs story", nothing will match if that doesn't exist, as it'll be looking for that whole string instead of looking for each word respectively.

I tried to break it down by exploding the string into an array and then imploding that and separating it with %'s, so a search like "steve jobs story" would be "steve%jobs%story", and with my query it would be "%steve%jobs%story%". When I try searching this, I get no error but the query finds nothing, whereas when I just type one word it works, so I'm guessing what I'm trying to do isn't allowed.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Here is my controller/model:

```
// Controller

$query = $request->get('q');

$explodedQuery = explode(" ", $query);
$newQuery = implode("%", $explodedQuery);

$articles = Article::isLikeTitle($newQuery)
                   ->isLikeBody($newQuery)
                   ->latest('published_at')
                   ->published()
                   ->paginate(10);

// Model

public function scopeIsLikeTitle($query, $q)
{
    return $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$q%");
}

public function scopeIsLikeBody($query, $q)
{
    return $query->where('body', 'LIKE', "%$q%");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use loop to append the query with orWhere like this

```
$query = $request->get('q');

$explodedQuery = explode(" ", $query);

$articles = Article::isLikeTitle($explodedQuery)
                   ->isLikeBody($explodedQuery)
                   ->latest('published_at')
                   ->published()
                   ->paginate(10);

// Model

public function scopeIsLikeTitle($query, $q)
{
    foreach($q as $eachQueryString)
    {    
        $query->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$eachQueryString .'%');
    }
    return $query;
}

public function scopeIsLikeBody($query, $q)
{
    foreach($q as $eachQueryString)
    {    
        $query->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%'.$eachQueryString .'%');
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Ah didn't think about looping, thanks! But is there a reason why my method doesn't work? Is it an invalid statement or what?

Comment: @Lansana yes your query is wrong. you have used LIKE "%steve%jobs%story%" this means that the title should start with anything followed by steve and followed by anything and again followed by jobs and so on.